# Positive test charge in in electric field of a positive point charge

Tags: electrostatics

If we put a positive test charge in in the electric field of a positive point charge, will this charge repel untill it reaches infinity

Comment: To be sure, the repelled charge will always be a finite distance away for any value of time, i.e., it can't 'reach infinity' in finite time.

Comment: Yeah you are very clever

Comment: @AlfredCentauri has a good point. The concept of infinity is not trivial and is used inappropriately all the time that often leads to incorrect results. So it was indeed a worthy clarification to improve the logic of your question while your sarcasm was out of place.

Comment: I was praising him i didnot mean any thing bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, as long as there are no other forces or obstacles.

There is no limit on the distance in the Coulomb's law, so there is always going to be some repelling force and, therefore, some acceleration.

So, not only the charge will keep moving to infinity, but it will continue gaining speed.

Comment: Shouldnot the speed get smaller the more the test charge go away from the source charge

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey The speed should be increasing. As long as a force is acting on the charge, it is accelerating, according to the Newton's second law $(F=ma)$, which means that it keeps gaining the speed.

Comment: But the force is decreasing while the test charge moving away this means that the acceleration is also decreasing, consequently the speed decreases

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey When acceleration is decreasing, the speed is still increasing, but not as quickly. $a=\frac {dv}{dt}$, so, as long as $a$ is positive, the speed is increasing.

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey Glad I could help.